# Disable specific day of specific months in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Disable specific day (i.e Sunday - Friday enable only Saturday) of Specific months (i.e 1st May - 28th September) using jQuery Datepicker.

And for rest of dates (29th September - 30 April) should allow to select all the week days.

Comment: It's in the documentation. https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Answer (score 0):

You can use this : https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

An example to enable only the saturday:

```
<input />

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [(date.getDay()==6)?1:0]
    }
});
```

**EDIT 1 :**

```
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        if((date.getMonth()<4) || (date.getMonth()>=8)){
            if(date.getMonth()==8 && date.getDate()<28){
            return[0];
          } else {
            return [1];
          } 
        } else {
            return [(date.getDay()==6)?1:0];
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: @gsmio83 correct. But I need it only for 1st may to 28 september dates.

Comment: @Bhavesh Chhabhaiya See edit 1, if i correctly understand you need only the saturdays from 1st may to 28 september and for all other period all the days.